# d3js v4: Add nodes to force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, force-layout, d3.js

I would like to render a **force-directed graph in d3js v4** and provide a function for **dynamically adding new nodes and links** to the simulation. My first attempt (see below) still has some major issues:

- Already existing nodes and links seem to be ignored by the force
  simulation after adding a link
- The bindings between simulation nodes and links and their SVG counterparts somehow doesn't work

I think I know all the examples (e.g., [[1](http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/6c602d7cb14b25c179a4),[2]](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288)) demonstrating similar functionality for v3, but I would like to do it with v4.

Thanks for your help!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/graph.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .links line {
                stroke: #aaa;
            }

            .nodes circle {
              pointer-events: all;
              stroke: none;
              stroke-width: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chart-container" style="max-width: 1000px;"></div>

        <button class="expand">Expand graph</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //sample graph dataset
            var graph = {
                "nodes": [
                    {"id": "A"},
                    {"id": "B"},
                    {"id": "C"},
                    {"id": "D"},
                    {"id": "E"},
                    {"id": "F"}
                ],
                "links": [
                    {"source": "B", "target": "A"},
                    {"source": "C", "target": "A"},
                    {"source": "D", "target": "A"},
                    {"source": "D", "target": "C"},
                    {"source": "E", "target": "A"},
                    {"source": "F", "target": "A"}
                ]
            }
            //graph container
            var targetElement = document.querySelector('.chart-container');

            var graph = new Graph(targetElement, graph);

            d3.selectAll('button.expand').on('click', function (){
                var nodes = [
                    {"id": "G", "group": 1}
                ];

                var links = [
                    {"source": "F", "target": "G", "value": 1}
                ];

                graph.expandGraph(links, nodes);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**graph.js**

```
var Graph = function(targetElement, graph) {

    var self = this,

        width = targetElement.offsetWidth,

        height = width / 2,

        svg = d3.select(targetElement).append('svg')
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height),

        simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                       .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
                       .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
                       .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2)),

        link = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "links")
                  .selectAll("line"),

        node = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "nodes")
                  .selectAll("circle"),

        update = function() {

            // Redefine and restart simulation
            simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
                      .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation.force("link")
                      .links(graph.links);

            // Update links
            link = link.data(graph.links);

            // Enter links
            link = link.enter().append("line");

            // Exit any old links
            link.exit().remove();

            // Update the nodes
            node = node.data(graph.nodes);

            // Enter any new nodes
            node = node.enter().append("circle")
                       .attr("r", 5)
                       .call(d3.drag()
                            .on("start", dragstarted)
                            .on("drag", dragged)
                            .on("end", dragended));

            // Exit any old nodes
            node.exit().remove();

            function ticked() {
                link
                    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                node
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
            }


        },

        dragstarted = function(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        },

        dragged = function(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
        },

        dragended = function(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        },

        expandGraph = function(links, nodes) {

            for (var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                console.log('adding node', nodes[i]);
                graph.nodes.push(nodes[i]);
            }

            for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
                console.log('adding link', links[i]);
                graph.links.push(links[i]);
            }

            update();

        };

        // Public functions
        this.expandGraph = expandGraph;

    update();

};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to `merge()` your nodes. I have updated your code quickly:

**graph.js**

```
var Graph = function(targetElement, graph) {

var self = this,

    width = targetElement.offsetWidth,

    height = width / 2,

    svg = d3.select(targetElement).append('svg')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height),

    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                   .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
                   .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
                   .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2)),

    linkGroup = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "links"),

    nodeGroup = svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "nodes"),

    update = function() {

        // Redefine and restart simulation
        simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
                  .on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link")
                  .links(graph.links);

        // Update links
        link = linkGroup
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(graph.links);

        // Enter links
        linkEnter = link
            .enter().append("line");

        link = linkEnter
            .merge(link);

        // Exit any old links
        link.exit().remove();

        // Update the nodes
        node = nodeGroup.selectAll("circle").data(graph.nodes);

        // Enter any new nodes
        nodeEnter = node.enter().append("circle")
                   .attr("r", 5)
                   .call(d3.drag()
                        .on("start", dragstarted)
                        .on("drag", dragged)
                        .on("end", dragended));

        node = nodeEnter.merge(node);

        // Exit any old nodes
        node.exit().remove();



        function ticked() {
            link
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        }


    },

    dragstarted = function(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    },

    dragged = function(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    },

    dragended = function(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    },

    expandGraph = function(links, nodes) {

        for (var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            console.log('adding node', nodes[i]);
            graph.nodes.push(nodes[i]);
        }

        for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
            console.log('adding link', links[i]);
            graph.links.push(links[i]);
        }

        update();

    };

    // Public functions
    this.expandGraph = expandGraph;

update();

};
```

Actually I don't understand this new function 100%, but you always need to merge your new links and nodes (i.e. `linkEnter` and `nodeEnter`) with your existing graph. If you don't do this, your old Graph kind of dies...

Mike Bostock made an example how to use `merge` here:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to port my v3 graphs to v4, thanks for sharing, it was useful. Actually, I copied your code locally to try it, when I click expand, a new node and link are generated, but the new node remains in the top left corner until I grab and move another node. Is it expected? Do you have the same issue? Many Thanks.

Comment: @Pierre you need to call simulation.restart(); to re-apply the coordinate.